# How to read more than ten million data from oracle in memory to process

Tags: java

I have a table store image location, now i want to write a program to read these image's location and download image, then use OCR to read text from image.
The problem is how to read more than ten million row from table into memory?

```
String sql = "select * from t_image where some condition";
Statement s = ...;
ResultSet set = s.executeQuery(sql);
while(set.next()) {//row is too much, how to optimize here?
    String location = set.getString("location");
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's already called BigData and you'll miss memory on your machine.

Comment: Whats wrong with reading and processing the data in batches that will fit in your available memory?

Comment: You keep an image as a table? Not as a BLOB?

Comment: be more specific in your condition in order to limit your data, if the data is still big, you can avoid the waiting by creating Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit your select query so it only returns x amount of rows. Then proccess it.